# Git: Create a new branch of a repo but keep submodules of "old" repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, git-submodules

I have the following problem: I created a repository with several submodules

```
repo:
-submodule1
-submodule2
-submodule3
....
```

i.e.

```
git branch --track VERSION_1 origin/VERSION_1    
git checkout VERSION_1
```

and

```
git submodule add <URL/TO/GIT> path/to/destination
```

for all my submodules.

Now, theres is an update of the repo where all the submodules are in. So I switch to a new branch and follow the new branch

```
git branch --track VERSION_2 origin/VERSION_2    
git checkout VERSION_2
```

Unfortunately, I have to add all my submodules again, or (which is a really bad idea) I have to ignore the submdoules in my repo:

```
echo /path/to/submodule/ >> .git/info/exclude
```

So, is there any chance to switch the branch of my repo to V2 and to bring the submodules to the new branch directly?

TIA!
Alex

Comment: Can you cherry pick the commit where you last updated the submodule (do that for evey submodule)? It will give you a conflict but that should be easy to solve with like "use mine", though I never tried it for submodules.

Comment: I think this is possible but I have to go through all my submodules, which I try to avoid. Therefore I seek for something like `git checkout VERSION_2 --keep_submodules` (which not exists!) ;)